# lazy instantiation of `textColor` in `UILabel` throws an error

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, lazy-loading, textcolor

If I uncomment `self.numberLabel.textColor = UIColor.black`, the build compiles but crashes in the simulator.

```
 lazy public var numberLabel: UILabel = {
        self.numberLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        return UILabel(frame: CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 40, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: 20))
    }()
```

> The error states: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Comment: How can you set the text color on something that hasn't been created yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not
>   calculated until the first time it is used. You indicate a lazy stored
>   property by writing the lazy modifier before its declaration.

Sample snippet -
 Swift 3.x

```
 lazy public var numberLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 21))
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    return label
}()



 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(numberLabel)
        numberLabel.text = "Good"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to numberLabel before you set it, best approach would be:

```
lazy public var numberLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 40, width:     self.bounds.size.width, height: 20))
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    return label
}()
```

As you can see the first "let label = " create the label, then all initialisations can be performed (like the textcolor), finally we return the label, to be assigned to the lazy property.